# Approximating energy needed to move an object with statistical information

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

I am stuck on following problem. It deals with energy needed to move object in lossless environment, but with lossy transmission of force that causes the movement. Imagine a vehicle moving in friction-less environment. From Newton's second law of motion we have

$$
  \eta F=ma
$$

where $\eta$ is efficiency of the engine dependent on speed $v(t)$. Assuming constant mass $m$, energy is

$$
  E=m\int_{0}^{d}{{\frac{a(s)}{\eta(v(s))}}{ds}}
$$

Main difficulty is that I do not know how function $v(s)$ looks like. I only know traveled distance $d$, average acceleration $\bar{a}$, probability distribution function of $v(s)$ and mapping of efficiency $\eta(v):\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$

I can make the problem tractable by assuming $\eta$ is constant, it yields $E=\frac{m\bar{a}d}{\eta}$. However, how can I find constant $\eta$ for good approximation of spent energy?

Comment: This may be better suited for the [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is there a way to move the question or should I just copy-paste it?

Comment: If enough people agree, it will be migrated automatically. You don't have to do anything.